# CSV to JSON using NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, fs

I'd like to convert a CSV file to a JSON object using NodeJS. The problem is that my CSV file is hosted on a special URL.

URL : [My CSV here](http://www.banque-france.fr/fileadmin/user_upload/banque_de_france/Economie_et_Statistiques/Changes_et_Taux/page3_quot.csv)

```
var fs = require("fs");
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream("myurl");
var converter = new Converter({constructResult:true});
converter.on("end_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
   console.log(jsonObj);
});
fileStream.pipe(converter);
```

Issue :

```
Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\GestionDettes\http:\www.banque-france.fr\fileadmin\user_upload\banque_de_france\Economie_et_Statistiques\Changes_et_Taux\page3_quot.csv'
at Error (native)
```

Edit #1 :

```
Request.get(myurl, function (error, Response, body) {
  var converter = new Converter({
    constructResult: true,
    delimiter: ';'
  });
  converter.fromString(body,function(err, taux){
    console.log(taux); // it works
  });
});
```

Comment: and what's the problem? you can not use http module to request the CSV file?

Comment: See `Issue` in my post.

Comment: you need to use the http module to request the CSV file, not the fs module

Comment: Ok so it works with `request.get()` but is that possible to remove the first 5 lines of the `body` result, it is the head of the CSV and I don't need it.. (see edit #1)

Comment: you'll have to split the string in line by the line separator used and then remove the lines that you do not need

Comment: Do you have a sample code?

Comment: here is not a chat, please describe your problem from A to Z and wait for an answer

Answer (score 0):

I did just that in a module reading and writing on different protocol in different data formats. I used `request` to get http resources.

If you want take a look at [alinex-datastore](https://gitlab.com). With this module it should work like:

```js
const DataStore = require('@alinex/datastore').default;

async function transform() {
    const ds = new DataStore('http://any-server.org/my.csv');
    await ds.load();
    await ds.save('file:/etc/my-app.json');
}
```

That should do it.